# Enable keyboard return key

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I would like to enable the keyboard return key only when some uitextfields are not empty.
I read this question 
[How to disable/enable the return key in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/disable-enable-return-key-in-uitextfield)

Is this the only way? Is it true this could cause Apple to reject the app?

Comment: just set textfield.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES. Apple already does it for developper.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method to prevent the return key from returning.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I would the keyboard return key "disactive" if there aren't particular conditions. Using textFieldShouldReturn: I prevent the return key from returning... I would that it was visually disabled.

Comment: I figured that that's what you meant; but using that method could at least be a work-around if there is no way to actually disable the button.

Comment: Yes, I have not explained well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Following thing will enable/disable return key automatically.

> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  {
>
>   ```
>    textfield.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
>
>   // your code here
>
>     return YES;  }
>   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a public API, so use it on your own risk.

```
textField.setValue(true/false, forKeyPath: "inputDelegate.returnKeyEnabled")
```

More detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70390263).