# How can I disable/enable UISearchBar keyboard's Search button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uikeyboard, uisearchbardelegate

I am using `UISearchBar` in my code. I have imported its delegate in header file and implemented some delegate methods in implementation file also.

When we tap on the `UISearchBar`, a keyboard will appear to enter text. The return key of the keyboard is "*Search*" button. It will disabled by default. When we enter a character, It will get enabled. (Am I right?)

Here the problem comes.. I want to enable the `UISearchBar` keyboard's return key when the user types atleast two letters.

Is it possible? If yes, how can we do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't disable the search button. What you can do is use the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods to figure out if you should take action on the search button being clicked, like so:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (searchBar.text.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Do search stuff here
    }
}
```

The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for this is very useful as well, and is a great starting point for customizing the searchBar's behavior.

Comment: But it's not clear for the user if the search button is active, but do nothing

Comment: Like @NikKov said. The problem is how to disable (change to gray color) search button.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no...

Longer, hackier and more exotic one is here:
[How to disable/enable the return key in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/disable-enable-return-key-in-uitextfield)

Comment: For specifically "Can I literally disable return key for searchbar", this is the correct answer. Except that OP's requirement could be fulfilled otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by accessing `UISearchBar` property.

```
let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
textFieldInsideSearchBar?.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
```

By playing with `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` property you can achieve your requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the setting you're looking for:

`searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it:

```
    if([searchbar.text length] == 0) {
        [searchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder)
                           withObject: nil
                           afterDelay: 0.1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
 - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
       if (searchText.length>=2) {
         [Main_SearchBar resignFirstResponder];

         // Do your code here
       }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
if([self.searchBar.text length] > 2)
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```