# Disabling the 'Search' button in the searchbar keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable/enable UISearchBar keyboard's Search button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721668/how-can-i-disable-enable-uisearchbar-keyboards-search-button)

Can we disable the 'Search' button in the keyboard for a search bar? I want to enable it after user enters 3 characters in the search bar.

Comment: Please check the below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721668/how-can-i-disable-enable-uisearchbar-keyboards-search-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can't do that. You need to implement UISearchBar's delegate

```
- searchBarSearchButtonClicked:
```

You can just add a condition in your delegate like:

```
 - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1 {
     if ([searchBar.text length] < 3){
          return;
     }
     else {
          // Do searching here or other stuffs
     }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a copy and paste of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9722139/419