# Disable UISearchBar search button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

Please don't mark my question as duplicate, I knew there are lots of answer which is similar to my question but I am not satisfied with their answer.

I need to disable the search button of `UISearchBar` until user type at least 3 characters. From all of the answer in stackoverflow most are recommending to implement
 `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`.

But this is not my requirement. I need exactly same that apple do when we not enter any character.

Comment: It is what's being asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721668/how-can-i-disable-enable-uisearchbar-keyboards-search-button/.  The answer is unsatisfying, because it says you can't do it, but it is the same question and I think we're stuck with the same, sad, answer (plagiarized below for your convenience).

Comment: @danh the link you have provided I am currently doing this.. but it's just stop to search but the UISearchBar search key still highlighted. How user will understand that they have to enter more text to search.

Comment: I don't know who added `This question may already have an answer here:` to him/her those answers doesn't fulfil my requirement. I have to disable the search button until it's satisfy the search criteria.