# Disable "GO" button in UIKeyboard until a certain condition is met

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I need to disable the "Go" button in my `UIKeyboard` until a certain condition is satisfied(text in `UITextField` must match a string in a saved array). I have tried `_theSearch.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically=NO;` inside the method `-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` but that doesn't work. What can be done here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable/enable return key in UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/disable-enable-return-key-in-uitextfield)

Comment: Tried that method and it didn't work

Comment: show your condition bro

Comment: Sorry bro..There is no public API for doing that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no other known public API to disable the GO key.

If you want to use conditions then you should implement the `delegate` method `textFieldShouldReturn`. Return `true` when the conditions are met and perform whatever the GO button is supposed to be doing.
Otherwise just return `false` and perhaps inform the user of the problem.

Comment: This will not work. He want to disable the "Go" button, but return false will not disable it.

Comment: The code will work just fine. There's no public API to disable the GO button

Comment: I knew there is no public API, I only concern that your answer doesn't fulfil what actually asked .

Comment: ok, updated my response. saying "not possible" and providing an alternative does not make the answer wrong.

Comment: I find this to be the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 (subclassing)

You can subclass `UITextField` and override `hasText` property:

```
class CustomTextField : UITextField {
    override public var hasText: Bool {
        get {
            return validateInput(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Where `validateInput(_ string: String?) -> Bool` checks against your needed input criteria, for example character count.

Of course this only works in combination with `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true` set on the `UITextField`.

### Option 2 (extending)

```
extension UITextFieldDelegate {
    func setReturnKeyState(for textField: UITextField, isEnabled: Bool, delay: Double? = nil) {
        textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        if textField.delegate != nil {
            if let delay = delay {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                    textField.setValue(isEnabled, forKeyPath: "inputDelegate.returnKeyEnabled")
                }
            } else {
                textField.setValue(isEnabled, forKeyPath: "inputDelegate.returnKeyEnabled")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Call setReturnKeyState in delegate methods, for example:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    setReturnKeyState(for: textField, isEnabled: validateInput(textField.text), delay: 0.1) // A bit hacky it needs delay here
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if var text = textField.text, let range = Range(range, in: text) {
        text.replaceSubrange(range, with: string)
        setReturnKeyState(for: textField, isEnabled: validateInput(text))
    }
    return true
}
```

Sample `validateInput()` implementation:

```
func validateInput(_ string: String?) -> Bool {
    (string?.count ?? 0) > 3
}
```

Answer (score -2):

While you have to use set the return key function for the Textfeilds and use the code as demo like

```
if (Condition True){
id keyboard = [self magicallyGetAUIKeyboardInstance];
[keyboard setReturnKeyEnabled: YES];
}
else {
id keyboard = [self magicallyGetAUIKeyboardInstance];
[keyboard setReturnKeyEnabled: NO];
}
```

You only have to enable and disable the Keyboard Return key functionality