# How to enable or disable the keyboard return key

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

When we enter character in textfield then it is enabling the return key. But in our requirement we need to enable the return key when length is more than 5. But now as soon as we enter character it is enabling the return key. Do we need to customize the keyboard or is there any other solution available. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` is what enables the key when there is data in the textfield. Perhaps you can check if the length is greater than or equal to 5 and set it to YES.. or Less than 5 and set it to NO.. Maybe in `UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate.

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working.

Answer (score -2):

Well I think you should handle it in the `UITextField` delegate :

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField {
     return textField.text.length > 0;
 }
```

Comment: or you can go with this approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/disable-enable-return-key-in-uitextfield