# iOS:Disable the return key in keyboard using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I tried - [How to disable/enable the return key in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/how-to-disable-enable-the-return-key-in-a-uitextfield) but this gives compilation error.

**Requirement :** Return key should be disabled until user enters 9 characters.

I tried `textfield.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;` Using this return key was disabled when no input text is available in text field.As soon as i enter text its becoming enable.

Is there any solution which works for this?

Comment: "but this gives compilation error" which one?

Comment: Don't think it's possible doing this _legally_. Might be worth checking this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/how-to-disable-enable-the-return-key-in-a-uitextfield

Comment: You can't do this, better use `textFieldShouldReturn` method and throw error if your condition not met, allow to return if it meets.

Answer (score 1):

please select "Auto Enable Return key"

[image]

Try this one its work for me

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (newString.length == 9) {

        self.txtTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;

    }

    return (newString.length<=10);
}
```

Comment: This only disable return key when there is no value in textfield, as soon as you enter a char in textfield the return key gets enabled, i want it to be disabled until 9 chars.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable returnKey with text in the `UITextField`. As specified in [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624432-enablesreturnkeyautomatically?language=objc)

> If you set it to YES, the keyboard disables the Return key when the text entry area contains no text.

For the behaviour you want to achieve, you can block the code that will be executed on click on returnKey

Conform your class to `UITextFieldDelegate`

Set the

```
textfield.delegate = self
```

Implement the protocol method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if( textField.text.length < 9)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextFieldDelegate method to find 9 characters, and enable key that time until disable it. show the code below:
I have written this code in swift you can write in Objective-C

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Limit to 9 characters
    if range.location >= 9 {
        txtCity.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
    } else { 
       txtCity.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
}
```

Comment: return key is automatically enabled only, i couldn't get it disabled

Comment: yes, but instead of textField you need to write your textField instance, and make sure delegate is self.

Comment: This method called every time when single character change in textField. Here also we can get length of string.

Comment: Yes i tried that as well, but as soon as you enter a single char, return key is enabled