# tvOS: How to disable Next and Done button on UIKeyBoard?

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos

After making usernameTextfield firstresponder, I see below screen for entering username.

[image: As of now Next button can be focused and after press takes me to next passwordfield screen]
I want to disble (or not focused) Next button until textfield has 0 characters. How can I do it? 
Also, how can I capture tv remotes Back and Press event on keyboard?

I read other post [How to disable/enable the return key in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788323/how-to-disable-enable-the-return-key-in-a-uitextfield) but It didn't helped me.

In apple docs, it's mentioned that

optional public var enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: Bool { get set } // default is NO (when YES, will automatically disable return key when text widget has zero-length contents, and will automatically enable when text widget has non-zero-length contents)

If this is not possible, then is it possible to add tapgesturerecognizer on this screen so that I can know when user click or pressed Menu button on Remote?

Comment: As of now my research says its not possible to disable return key in tvOS but its possible to know when user clicked Next or Done button on keyboard by using .primaryActionTriggered event.

Comment: did you got any workaround same problem..?

Comment: Did someone has a chance to find a radar or any documentation related to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As of now my research says its not possible to disable return key ( Next / Done ) in tvOS but its possible to know when user clicked Next or Done button on keyboard by using .primaryActionTriggered event.