# Enable keyboard Search Button on condition only

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

I want to enable the search button in keyboard after 3 characters are entered by the user. Is it possible?

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("test")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46003924/7734643 this might help.